# Can't create database using variable with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create databases in SQL Server 2012 with this script

```
DECLARE @userdb varchar(30)
SET @userdb = 'DB_testing'

CREATE DATABASE @userdb
```

but I get this error message

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect Syntax near '@userdb'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use dynamic SQL

```
 declare @userdb varchar(30)
 SET @userdb = 'DB_testing'

 declare @sql nvarchar(111);
 set @sql = 'create database  '+ @userdb 

 Exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use dynamic SQL as shown in the other answers or you can use SQLCMD.

```
:SETVAR userdb "DB_testing"

CREATE DATABASE $(DB_userdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass variable into basic `CREATE DATABASE` statement,  you will need dynamic SQL

```
declare @sql varchar(30) @userdb varchar(30)
SET @userdb = 'DB_testing'
SET @sql = 'create database ' + QUOTENAME(@userdb)
exec (@sql)
```